# Xamarin Forms PCL how to PushAsync From iOS customRenderer

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I struggling to find a solution to this
Lets hope someone can point me to the right direction.

I need to Navigate to a `Forms` `ContentPage` like:

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new ExamplePage());
```

but then from my `CustomRenderer` class in my iOS project.
How can i achieve this ?

**Why you want to do this?**

Since im making a `CustomRenderer` for my `WebView`
and i want to redirect an `Url` to my internal `Forms` `ContentPage` in the `ShouldStartLoad` event.

Comment: You could add `event` to your `CustomWebView` and then raise from renderer.

Comment: TY thats was the thing stupid i didnt think about that myself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `event` to your `CustomWebView` and then raise from renderer.